# amcharts customized label position

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, label, amcharts

Right now my graph's label is placed in a default position, but my label texts are rather long and its sticking out from the graph.

If possible, I want to place it so that the labels don't stick out from the graph.

[Pic of Current situation & Ideal graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWenw.png)

Or if the above is not possible, I want to fix the visible labels. Is this possible? 
right now, the "best" label gets lost/hidden when the graph width is reduced. The "too much" label also gets lost when the width is largely reduced.

I have been searching all over stackoverflow and amcharts website but I can't seem to find a good solution.
Is there any way to solve either of the problems...?

```
// tried these but doesnt work for what I want to do
va.labelOffset = -5;
va.position = "bottom";
va.inside = false;
```

[full code in JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yukah3/12f7qq7r/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to keep the chart from hiding the labels on resize, you need to disable the valueAxis' [`autoGridCount`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#autoGridCount) and set the [`gridCount`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#gridCount) to the number of tick marks you want to see. You'll also need to remove the labelFrequency setting.

```
va.autoGridCount = false;
va.gridCount = 3;
//va.labelFrequency = 5;
```

As for label positioning, you are limted to rotating and vertical offsets out of the box. As a workaround, you can position the labels by modifying the SVG nodes directly through the [`drawn`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#drawn) event, for example:

```
// prior to chart.write
chart.addListener("drawn", function(e) {
  var textNodes = e.chart.valueAxes[0].labelsSet.node.childNodes;
  var transform;

  //Position "too little"
  transform = parseTransform(textNodes[0].getAttribute('transform'));
  transform.translate[0] = parseFloat(transform.translate[0]) + 25;
  textNodes[0].setAttribute('transform', serializeTransform(transform));
  // Position "too much"
  transform = parseTransform(textNodes[2].getAttribute('transform'));
  transform.translate[0] = parseFloat(transform.translate[0]) - 25;
  textNodes[2].setAttribute('transform', serializeTransform(transform));

});

// ...

// from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824145/parse-svg-transform-attribute-with-javascript
function parseTransform(a) {
  var b = {};
  for (var i in a = a.match(/(\w+\((\-?\d+\.?\d*e?\-?\d*,?)+\))+/g)) {
    var c = a[i].match(/[\w\.\-]+/g);
    b[c.shift()] = c;
  }
  return b;
}

//serialize transform object back to an attribute string
function serializeTransform(transformObj) {
  var transformStrings = [];
  for (var attr in transformObj) {
    transformStrings.push(attr + '(' + transformObj[attr].join(',') + ')');
  }
  return transformStrings.join(',');
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12f7qq7r/1/)