# AmChart move labelText to right a few pixels

Tags: amcharts

I'm trying to move label test to right few pixels because the way it's displayed now it looks like it is more  to the left:[image]

Label text is aligned to center for 2d bar charts but when you have 3d bars you have this slight offset effect to left that needs to be corrected.Label position values are: "bottom", "top", "right", "left", "inside", "middle".
I wasn't able to fine tune it.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: The labels are more or less centered with respect to the `angle` setting when using 3D. There isn't an API-specific setting to fine-tune the labels left or right, so you're better off using the `drawn`/`rendered` events to select the labels using DOM methods and adjust the position that way. If you need more help with this, update the question with a fiddle that reproduces your chart.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cdedu/wc12oxdh/18/  -> this is an example close to my chart. I did not spent time updating the colors and all that. But you get the same problem as the label is a bit to the left. so this jsfiddle pretty much describes my problem.

Comment: @otto wow plus one for the visualization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the labels are centered with respect to the `angle` setting for 3D charts. The API doesn't allow you to shift the label left or right, so you have to manipulate the graph SVG nodes directly through the [`drawn`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#drawn) event. If you set [addClassNames](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#addClassNames) to `true`, you can retrieve the label elements using `document.querySelectorAll` through the [generated DOM class names](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/css-class-names/) and then modifying the `translate` value in the `transform` attribute accordingly. You can use a technique from [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824145/parse-svg-transform-attribute-with-javascript) to easily manipulate the transform attribute as an object:

```
// ...
  "addClassNames": true,
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "drawn",
    "method": function(e) {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(
        document.querySelectorAll(".amcharts-graph-g4 .amcharts-graph-label"),
        function(graphLabel) {
          var transform = parseTransform(graphLabel.getAttribute('transform'));
          transform.translate[0] = parseFloat(transform.translate[0]) + 5; //adjust X offset
          graphLabel.setAttribute('transform', serializeTransform(transform));
      });
    }
  }]
// ...

// from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824145/parse-svg-transform-attribute-with-javascript
function parseTransform(a) {
  var b = {};
  for (var i in a = a.match(/(\w+\((\-?\d+\.?\d*e?\-?\d*,?)+\))+/g)) {
    var c = a[i].match(/[\w\.\-]+/g);
    b[c.shift()] = c;
  }
  return b;
}

//serialize transform object back to an attribute string
function serializeTransform(transformObj) {
  var transformStrings = [];
  for (var attr in transformObj) {
    transformStrings.push(attr + '(' + transformObj[attr].join(',') + ')');
  }
  return transformStrings.join(',');
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wc12oxdh/29/)

Comment: thanks! It worked for me with `animationFinished` event due to animations set in my chart but this is the solution