# Parse SVG transform attribute with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, svg

How do I parse the transform attribute of svg elements using typescript?

That is, how can I parse all the numbers and operations in the string at svg.g.transform in the following:

```
<svg viewBox="-40 0 150 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g fill="grey"
     transform="rotate(-10 50 100)
                translate(-36 45.5)
                skewX(40)
                scale(1 0.5)">
    <path id="heart" d="M 10,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30 Q 90,60 50,90 Q 10,60 10,30 z" />
  </g>

  <use xlink:href="#heart" fill="none" stroke="red"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement aka. `SVGLocatable` and `SVGTransformable` interfaces/API that is implemented by the native  DOM elements.

These elements have a `.transform` property that corresponds to the transform attribute. This property has the type https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedTransformList and you want to look at the statically defined baseVal.

The transform list has an attribute `numberOfItems` and a `getItem` method. It may have a `.length`property and `[]` array accessor and it may be iterable in your browser, but don't count on that.

Each item has the type https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGTransform

The `.type` property tells you which instruction was used.

Therefore, here is how you can parse and then manually synthesize the transform attribute again:

```
// javascript js equivalent declaration:
// function getAttributeTransform_js(nativeSVGElement) {
// typescript ts declaration
function getAttributeTransform_ts(nativeSVGElement: SVGGraphicsElement) {
  // this definition works in ts and js
  const tl = nativeSVGElement.transform.baseVal;
  const st = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < tl.numberOfItems; i++) {
    const t/*: SVGTransform*/ = tl.getItem(i);
    switch (t.type) {
      case SVGTransform.SVG_TRANSFORM_UNKNOWN: break;
      case SVGTransform.SVG_TRANSFORM_MATRIX: {
        // A matrix(…) transformation
        // Note: this is the most general transformation, capable of representing more transformations than the other combined.
        // For SVG_TRANSFORM_MATRIX, the matrix contains the a, b, c, d, e, f values supplied by the user.
        //
        // Note: instead of comma (,), whitespace separation would also be allowed
        st.push(`matrix(${t.matrix.a}, ${t.matrix.b}, ${t.matrix.c}, ${t.matrix.d}, ${t.matrix.e}, ${t.matrix.f})`);
        break;
      }
      case SVGTransform.SVG_TRANSFORM_TRANSLATE: {
        // A translate(…) transformation
        // For SVG_TRANSFORM_TRANSLATE, e and f represent the translation amounts (a=1, b=0, c=0 and d=1).
        st.push(`translate(${t.matrix.e}, ${t.matrix.f})`);
        break;
      }
      case SVGTransform.SVG_TRANSFORM_SCALE: {
        // A scale(…) transformation
        // For SVG_TRANSFORM_SCALE, a and d represent the scale amounts (b=0, c=0, e=0 and f=0).
        st.push(`scale(${t.matrix.a}, ${t.matrix.d})`);
        break;
      }
      case SVGTransform.SVG_TRANSFORM_ROTATE: {
        // A rotate(…) transformation
        // For SVG_TRANSFORM_ROTATE, a, b, c, d, e and f together represent the matrix which will result in the given rotation.
        // When the rotation is around the center point (0, 0), e and f will be zero.
        /*
        angle   float   A convenience attribute for SVG_TRANSFORM_ROTATE, SVG_TRANSFORM_SKEWX and SVG_TRANSFORM_SKEWY. It holds the angle that was specified.

        For SVG_TRANSFORM_MATRIX, SVG_TRANSFORM_TRANSLATE and SVG_TRANSFORM_SCALE, angle will be zero.
        */
        /*
        This is the hardest case since the origin information is lost!
        We need to recompute it from the matrix.
        from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093314/rotation-matrix-of-rotation-around-a-point-other-than-the-origin

        matrix.a = cos_angle = c;
        matrix.b = sin_angle = s;
        Note that by the laws of geometry: c^2+s^2 = 1 (c and s are coordinates on the unit circle)
        matrix.e = -x*c + y*s + x;
        matrix.f = -x*s - y*c + y;

        Using Mathematica/Wolfram Language:
        "Assuming[c^2+s^2==1,Solve[e == -x*c + y*s + x&& f == -x*s - y*c + y,{x,y},Reals]//Simplify]//InputForm"
        (you can use WL for free here: https://develop.wolframcloud.com/objects/c26e16f7-44e7-4bb6-81b3-bc07782f9cc5)
        {{x -> (e + (f*s)/(-1 + c))/2, y -> (f - c*f + e*s)/(2 - 2*c)}}
        */
        const e = t.matrix.e, f = t.matrix.f, c = t.matrix.a, s = t.matrix.b;
        const originx = (e + (f*s)/(-1 + c))/2;
        const originy = (f - c*f + e*s)/(2 - 2*c);
        st.push(`rotate(${t.angle}, ${originx}, ${originy})`);
        break;
      }
      case SVGTransform.SVG_TRANSFORM_SKEWX: {
        // A skewx(…) transformation
        // For SVG_TRANSFORM_SKEWX and SVG_TRANSFORM_SKEWY, a, b, c and d represent the matrix which will result in the given skew (e=0 and f=0).
        /*
        angle   float   A convenience attribute for SVG_TRANSFORM_ROTATE, SVG_TRANSFORM_SKEWX and SVG_TRANSFORM_SKEWY. It holds the angle that was specified.

        For SVG_TRANSFORM_MATRIX, SVG_TRANSFORM_TRANSLATE and SVG_TRANSFORM_SCALE, angle will be zero.
        */
        st.push(`skewx(${t.angle})`);
        break;
      }
      case SVGTransform.SVG_TRANSFORM_SKEWY: {
        // A skewy(…) transformation
        // For SVG_TRANSFORM_SKEWX and SVG_TRANSFORM_SKEWY, a, b, c and d represent the matrix which will result in the given skew (e=0 and f=0).
        /*
        angle   float   A convenience attribute for SVG_TRANSFORM_ROTATE, SVG_TRANSFORM_SKEWX and SVG_TRANSFORM_SKEWY. It holds the angle that was specified.

        For SVG_TRANSFORM_MATRIX, SVG_TRANSFORM_TRANSLATE and SVG_TRANSFORM_SCALE, angle will be zero.
        */
        st.push(`skewy(${t.angle})`);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return st.join(','); // instead of comma (,), whitespace separation is also allowed
}
```

```
// example
const r = <SVGRectElement>document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");

// the parseable syntax for the transform attribute is pretty relaxed
r.setAttribute("transform", "translate(1, 0),rotate(0.5),   scale(1 2)");

// note that the browser may canonicalize your syntax
// EDGE canonicalizes the transform to read:
// 'translate(1) rotate(0.5) scale(1, 2)'
console.log(r.getAttribute("transform"));

// basically equivalent:
console.log(getAttributeTransform_ts(r));
```

Your example:

```
function createElementFromHTML(htmlString) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = htmlString.trim();

  // Change this to div.childNodes to support multiple top-level nodes
  return div.firstChild; 
}

getAttributeTransform_ts(createElementFromHTML(`
<g fill="grey"
     transform="rotate(-10 50 100)
                translate(-36 45.5)
                skewX(40)
                scale(1 0.5)">
    <path id="heart" d="M 10,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30 Q 90,60 50,90 Q 10,60 10,30 z" />
  </g>
`))

// gives
// 'rotate(-10, 49.99999999999982, 99.99999999999972),translate(-36, 45.5),skewx(40),scale(1, 0.5)'
```

Note that you should use `.getAttribute("transform")` to let the browser synthesize the string form of an SVGTransformList for you, instead of using my script above!

Note that we cannot retrieve the origin argument of "rotate" perfectly, because there is no API for it. It has to be computed from the 2d-homogeneous (rotation) matrix.

Inspired by:

- [Parse SVG transform attribute with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824145/parse-svg-transform-attribute-with-javascript)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41102221/524504

See also:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform